# Переключение карточек с текстом с помощью кнопок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать переключение карточки с текстом, относящимся к конкретной дате?
И как убрать движение между кнопками при переключениями?

```js
var btnActive = document.querySelectorAll(".time-btn");

for (var button of btnActive) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        btnActive.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active-btn'));

        this.classList.toggle('active-btn');
    });
};
```

```js
var btnActive = document.querySelectorAll(".time-btn");

for (var button of btnActive) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        btnActive.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active-btn'));

        this.classList.toggle('active-btn');
    });
};
```

```css
.times-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px;
}

.time-btn {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: #03a898;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.active-btn {
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid #03a898;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.factory-store-card {
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.factory-img-style {
    max-width: 480px;
    max-height: 310px;
}

.card-date {
    margin-bottom: 38px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-date-text {
    color: #03a898;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="factory-store-inner">
                    <h2 class="factory-store-title">История завода</h2>
                    <div class="times-buttons">
                        <button class="time-btn active-btn" id="time-btn">1931-1961</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">1973-1987</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">1992-1996</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2002-2008</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2009-2012</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2012-2014</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2015-2017</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2018-2020</button>
                        <button class="time-btn" id="time-btn">2021-2023</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="factory-store-card row">
                        <div class="factory-img col-6">
                            <img class="factory-img-style" src="images/traktor-test.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="about-date col-6">
                            <h3 class="card-date">1931-1961</h3>
                            <p class="card-date-text">Тут текст, относящийся к конкретной дате</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как убрать движение кнопок. При клике вы добавляете рамку, но изначально их нет, соответственно это должно вас натолкнуть на определенную мысль. (я бы просто добавил прозрачную рамку изначально, а далее красил бы ее в нужный цвет при клике-наведении)
Далее, как менять информацию в зависимости от даты. По идее, вы же эту инфу с сервера тянете, значит,вам нужно посылать запрос при клике на определенную кнопку. Соответственно, вам должен приходить заранее готовый текст. И вы его просто отображаете.

Чтобы все работало без перезагрузки, юзайте аякс

Comment: Да, спасибо. Реализовал прозрачные бордеры и теперь текст не двигается. Остался вопрос с переключением текста

Comment: Так я же написал про текст тоже. Если что-то не так, ответьте, что именно, какие условия не совпадают

Comment: В целом эти заготовки я могу сразу в HTML написать, они изменяться не будут. При клике на другую дату активный блок отобразится, а предыдущий скроется.

Comment: Смотрите, ваш вариант, похоже на слайдер. Как по мне, лучше с сервера тянуть, отображать легче.

Comment: А если попробовать реализовать как слайдер? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Как слайдер... Анимация должна быть при переходе на следующую дату?

Comment: Плавная анимация при переходе (уточнил)

Comment: Мой совет. Попробуйте взять готовую библиотеку слайдер, типо slick.js И попробовать ее модифицировать, или же (скорее всего), придется писать свое